# Deploy VM in FIWARE Lab Nodes with Neutron

Tags: fiware, filab

Some of the nodes part of FIWARE Lab offer more complex configurations. What is the purpose of "Networks" and what is the purpose of "Routers"? How to use them?

Answer (score 1):

Some nodes in the FIWARE Lab use OpenStack Neutron for network provisioning (e.g. Waterford, Budapest). This means that the node enables you to set-up your own private network that is not share with other tenants (even though some of the nodes, may provide a default shared network like in node using nova-network). "Networks" panel helps you to set-up such a network, while "Routers" enables you to interconnect your private-network to the external world.

How to proceed to create a VM in such nodes?

1. select the network pane and create a network including a subnet
   (e.g. 192.168.12.0/24)
2. select the router pane and create a router
3. select the created router and set the default gateway
4. click on the created router and select the interface pane; add as interface the subnet of your network
5. click on security pane, select keypar panel, create a keypar
6. select floating ip panel, and allocate a public ip to the project
7. click on image pane, select the image and click launch. set the the flavour, security roules and the network you created up-front.
8. wait the vm to be active
9. click on the secutiry panel, select the floating IPs, and attach the reserved IP to your vm